# OleDbDataAdapter.Update() with OleDbCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

I am hitting an Oracle database using C# and OleDb, I have sucessfully pulled data from a query but I am unable to update the database using `OleDbAdapter.Update()`, my update code is below. ("Adapter" is a reference to the `OleDbAdapter` object used to sucessfully pull data out of the database.)

```
OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter);
Adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
Adapter.UpdateCommand.Prepare();
Adapter.Update(ds);
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

I am currently getting a "Command was not prepared." error on the first line of the above code. Any suggestions and I would be very grateful.

(Edit: ds is the DataSet)

Comment: it's rather hard to tell without seeing what the build returns. Sometimes the builder is not able to build a command from your Select - can you give us both - the select-query and the generated Update?

Comment: How can I get a hold of the generated Update? Note that the code throws an exception on the first line (OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter);) and so Adapter.UpdateCommand is null beforehand. My select query is actually a stored procedure which pulls id, firstName and lastName from a simple table.

Comment: sorry missed the "first line" comment - don't know exactly but is the Select in the Adapter right? Please set a breakpoint and insprect the Adapter-object for those Commands.

Comment: The select is a stored procedure, and that pulls the correct data from the database, I have unit tested it thoroughly. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: ok - how is the CommandBuilder suppost to generate a update based on a stored procedure? You have to come up with such an update-expression yourself.

Comment: wow ok, I thought the commandbuilder looked at the dataset returned, but thinking about mroe complicated examples which aren't just a single table that kinda makes sense, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your version is not working because you query a stored procedure.

If you think of it: to work it needs all the information like keys and so on. What if you join tables in your stored procedure and select only a subset of rows without some important primary-keys?

In those cases you might need to write/get a stored procedure or query yourself and give it to the adapter.

Comment: Thanks, that dawned on me after your last comment, makes sense when you think about it.